# When I saving an object, NHibernate tries to save object in database with id=0

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have NHibernate --version 2.1.2.4000 and use NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes

When i want to save object, like that

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(car);
session.Flush();
```

I have an exception **"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Car' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."** This happens when NHibernate tries set sql script with ID=0, like that

```
"exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Car (...., Id) VALUES (.., @p12)',N'...,@p12 int', @p12=0 go"
```

My class has the following attribute

```
public class Car: ILifecycle {
    [Generator(Class = "identity")]
    [Id(0, Name = "Id", Column = "Id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }  
    public virtual LifecycleVeto OnDelete(ISession s);
    public virtual void OnLoad(ISession s, object id);
    public virtual LifecycleVeto OnSave(ISession s);
    public virtual LifecycleVeto OnUpdate(ISession s);
}
```

Nhibernate helper has the following setting

```
public class NhibernateHelper {
        private readonly string _configurePath;
        /// <param name="path"></param>
        public NhibernateHelper(string path) {
            _configurePath = path;
        }
        /// <summary>The session factory.</summary>
        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;

        /// <summary>Gets current session.</summary>
        /// <returns>The current session.</returns>
        public static ISession GetCurrentSession() {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        /// <summary>Connects to database 1.</summary>
        public void ConnectToDb() {

            var configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.Configure(_configurePath);


            HbmSerializer.Default.Validate = true;
            Stream s = HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            configuration.AddInputStream(s);
            
            var assembly = Assembly.Load("DAL");
            s = HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(assembly);
            configuration.AddInputStream(s);

            SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

        }
        public void CloseSessionFactory() {
            if (SessionFactory != null)
                SessionFactory.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot about numbers before attributes.  [Generator(1, Class = "identity")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about the numbers before the attributes.[Generator(1, Class = "identity")]